# Ubuntu 12.04 lts fails to load unity. Nvidia persistence daemon [fail]

Tags: 12.04, asus, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Ubuntu 12.04 fails to start when my drivers are installed for nvidia.

When I’ve a ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop without the drivers installed, everything works just fine . But when I install my nvidia drivers and bumblebbee it start to the terminal. What do I’ve to do? These are the errors I’ve when booting Ubuntu through recovery mode. Because I get on low graphic mode when I don't enter GRUB.

```
could not write bytes: broken pipe
could not write bytes: bad file descriptor
Nvidia Persistence daemon [fail]
I’ve a asus ux32vd with i7 and NVIDIA [GeForce GT 620M]
```

I have spent one week googling around. None of the solutions I found helps. Help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here is the update. I was able to load my system with graphics enabled.
After I've posted this question I have re-installed my Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit. Then I have installed bumblebee following this [post](http://followthegeeks.com/a-noobs-guide-to-installing-nvidia-optimus-driver-in-ubuntu/).
Everything worked until I have installed freeglut3 using thise command:

```
 sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
```

I have noticed that it asks to delete a lot of files, libraries which are related to x-server. (I only deduced this from the names of files it asked to delete). 
I confirmed. After freglut3 was installed, I rebooted my system and had the same problem again.

```
could not write bytes: broken pipe
could not write bytes: bad file descriptor
Nvidia Persistence daemon [fail]
```

I decided to try to purge nvidia and bumblebee and re-install them, hoping that it will reload the files which freeglut3 deleted.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get --purge remove bumblebee
```

After thatб I have added repositories containing latest nvidia drivers and installed them.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

After the installation was complete **without** rebooting I have installed bumblebee

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

I have rebooted, and my system started working again!
Unfortunately I will have to do this each and every time some updates or new installations touch "X" files.
Hope this post helps somebody. Regards.